# Formato correcto para menú en web

Tags: html, css

Tengo el siguiente menú:

```
<ul class="topMenu">
    <li>
        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="">
        <p>Winset</p>
        <a class="fa fa-twitter" href="https://www.google.es"></a>
        <a class="fa fa-instagram" href="https://www.google.es"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Con el siguiente CSS:

```
/* TOP MENU OF THE PAGE */
.topMenu {
    background-color: black;
    font-size: 30px;
    list-style-type: none;
    color: white;
    text-align: right;
}
.topMenu a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.topMenu a:hover {
    color: yellow;
}
.topMenu img {
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
}
.topMenu p {
    float: left;
}
```

Tengo un problema a la hora de ajustar todos los elementos al mismo nivel en le menu, ya que se ven de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría alinear todos los elementos dentro del `topMenu`, pero no se como hacer que estén a la misma altura, ¿alguna sugerencia?

Si alguien tiene también alguna sugerencia para mejorar el HTML que he añadido se lo agradecería, ya que estoy empezando y cualquier consejo es bienvenido.

¡Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo usaría `Flexbox` para poder hacerlo mas rápido te muestro el código que implemente y te explico adentro de el para que sirven, por otro lado si te interesa aprender mas sobre `Flexbox` te dejo este [Link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
/* TOP MENU OF THE PAGE */
.topMenu {
    display: flex; /*Convertimos al menú en flexbox*/
    justify-content: space-between; /*Con esto le indicamos que margine todos los items que se encuentra adentro hacia la derecha e izquierda*/
    align-items: center; /*con esto alineamos de manera vertical*/
    background: #000;
    padding: 30px 0px;
    color: #fff;
}
.topMenu ul {
    list-style: none;
}
.topMenu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.logo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.logo span {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topMenu">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="img/logo.png" alt="">
      <span>Winset</span>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li>F</li>
      <li>T</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Por cierto estas cometiendo un error en utilizar una lista e insertar todo ahí adentro como logo o texto, te recomiendo que la etiqueta `ul` solo lo utilices si se trata de una lista ejemplo los ítems del menú.

Espero ayudarte con esto, cualquier cosa me comentas, Suerte!

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. El logo esta a una altura diferente de la resta de elementos en mi prueba...

Comment: Cambia `<p>Winset</p>` por `<span>Winset</span>`

Comment: Ha funcionado, gracias. Que diferencia supone el elemento `p` del `span`?

Comment: ahí edite y lo puse para que se centre el `span` acorde a la altura de la `img`

Comment: **span** - Es un contenedor en línea. Sirve para aplicar estilo al texto o agrupar elementos en línea.

**p** - Es el apropiado para distribuir el texto en párrafos.